# RegEx in Notepad++ to find a wild character and replace the whole word

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-editor

I have a test file with number values as below:

```
32405494
32405495
32405496
32407498
```

Using Notepad++, what I am trying to achieve here is to search the first 4 digits using regular expression and replace the whole number with `G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL`

I am able to find these values using `3240*`. My question is, how do I replace the whole number with `G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL`?

When I am click the Replace All button, I get the following output:

```
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL5494
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL5495
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL5496
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL7498
```

However, I am expecting the following:

```
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL
G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL
```

Any ideas to achieve this? Is it even possible through Notepad++? Are there any other text editors which I can use to achieve this?

Comment: You're probably confused between quantifiers and globs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
3240.*
```

`.` is the wildcard character in regex and `*` means that the previous character is to be repeated 0 or more times (your current regex actually matches `324` and then `0` which appears 0 or more times).

`3240.*` will therefore match `3240` and any other following characters.

You might also want to add a line anchor:

```
^3240.*
```

So that you don't replace numbers having `3240` in the middle too.

Answer (score 0):

in notepad++, you can use this regex:

```
^3240\d+
```

it will match the four digits you're searching at the beginning of your string followed by any digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Search this - ^3240\d*$
Replace with- G3E_STYLERULE_SEQ.NEXTVAL
```